# C# String.Replace and UTF-8 chars

Tags: c#, string, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to replace some of the [Romanian characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Romanian_characters) in this string with my own chars, but it's not really working.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sometext = "Încă nu s-a pornit acasă";
    sometext.Replace("ă", "1");

    Console.WriteLine(sometext);
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

<s>This outputs the original `sometext` without any changes. However, neither without replacing nor with replacing the final result is `Inca nu s-a pornit acasa`. Diacritics are replaced with the `ISO-8859-1` characters corresponding to them. `Î` becomes `I`, `ă` becomes `a`.</s>

### Sumarry:

The expected result is: `Înc1 nu s-a pornit acas1`.

Actually, I get: `Inca nu s-a pornit acasa`

**Note**: In `Advanced Save Options`, I've selected the following encoding: `Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001`

### Acutally, strings are immutable and String.Replace returns a string, so `sometext = sometext.Replace("ă", "1");` works just fine. Thanks to all!

Comment: Can the Console really handle utf8 characters?

Comment: Cant count how many times someone asks this question because of misunderstanding `String.Replace`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace does not mutate the string, it returns a string with the replacements so your code should be:

```
sometext = sometext.Replace(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sometext = "Încă nu s-a pornit acasă";
    sometext = sometext.Replace("ă", "1");

    Console.WriteLine(sometext);
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

or

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sometext = "Încă nu s-a pornit acasă".Replace("ă", "1");

    Console.WriteLine(sometext);
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

or whatever, [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) returns the string

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable. So do `sometext = sometext.Replace(...)`.

Comment: @develroot: It's because you are not assigning sometext back to itself. strings are immutable.

Answer (score 2):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sometext = "Încă nu s-a pornit acasă";
    sometext = sometext.Replace("ă", "1");

    Console.WriteLine(sometext);
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

try this...